# Serve a form without a web interface

Tags: forms, offline

Anyone doing any work using "offline" forms?  We have an application that requires inputting data from outside our company.  I was thinking about sending a form out via email, allowing the form to be filled out then sent back.  Obviously a web application would be the best solution, but management doesn't seem ready to build the infrastructure and security to support that.  I've read a little about PDF forms is that a good solution or are there other solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered InfoPath? These can be created and distributed through email. And then the data can be collated automatically.

Also, consider using Google Spreadsheets with Google Forms. It's free and infrastructure is outsourced.

PDF forms can work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use [Microsoft SharePoint](http://www.microsoft.com/Sharepoint/default.mspx). If your company uses Microsoft Office for the people filling the forms you referring to, you could deploy an Office based solution and gather information with [Sharepoint Server](http://www.microsoft.com/sharepoint/prodinfo/what.mspx).

[Check this link out](http://www.microsoft.com/sharepoint/capabilities/bpf/overview.mspx).